# Same Application Behaving Differently in Two Machine

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am getting this exception while launching  Apache Flume :

```
2021-04-20 20:04:11,463 (qtp39926397-25) [WARN - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handleException(HttpChannel.java:600)] 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Attributes.unwrap(Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/Attributes;)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/Attributes;
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.recycle(Request.java:1870)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.recycle(HttpChannel.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.recycle(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onCompleted(HttpConnection.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using `<jetty.version>9.4.30.v20200611</jetty.version>`.

The thing is it running fine in my local machine but when i try to my application in the VM it's throwing me this error not sure what's wrong ?

I checked the dependency using `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util`
and didn't find any different version.

Comment: Time to consider [containerization](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/cloud/learn/containerization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deployment on Apache Flume is using a version of Jetty older than 9.4.29 (where `Attributes.unwrap()` was first introduced).

Double check the startup logs of the Jetty server, it will announce the version it thinks it is running.

Example:

```
2021-04-20 16:37:05.615:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.40.v20210413; built: 2021-04-13T20:42:42.668Z; git: b881a572662e1943a14ae12e7e1207989f218b74; jvm 11.0.10+9

or 

2021-04-20 16:37:22.790:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.25.v20180904, build timestamp: 2018-09-04T16:11:46-05:00, git hash: 3ce520221d0240229c862b122d2b06c12a625732
```

Comment: I have updated Avro version of Flume via this PR - https://github.com/apache/flume/pull/331

Comment: I am not sure what i am doing wrong, any idea will be very helpful

Comment: yes you are right it's taking the older version `9.4.6.v20170531` inspite of updating in the pom any idea why is it so ?
I have build the project tar and when i run it locally it's taking the correct version not sure why is it  when i run it on VM machine ?

Comment: not sure why is it taking wrong version when  i run it on VM machine ?

Comment: It could be a bad mix of versions as well, consider using the `jetty-bom` (pom) to force the versions of all jetty artifacts, regardless of where they come from.

Comment: no luck, one thing our service is behind the Load balancer with lb it's working fine so wondering anything wrong there ?